# What is the mathematical logic behind basic algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, foundations

I am a freshman college student taking a required algebra course. This content should be very easy, but I have struggled with the more complicated applications of algebra since I was young. So I have decided to familiarize myself with the foundations of algebra to give myself a solid foundation before reattempting learning the algebra, more out of interest than necessity - I know I could learn the steps by rote. (I'm more of a big-picture thinker. The issue comes down to getting myself together to solve the actual practical questions during the exams).

The content includes factoring, rational equations, and solving polynomials, the only subjects I'm really concerned with. What types of logic do these algebraic operations and problems stem from and use? How are they/were they proven? I have experience with basic first order, Boolean, predicate, propositional, and modal logic. Where should I begin? General mathematical logic? Boolean algebra? I'm overwhelmed. Any book recommendations, links, even just a general overview of what subjects I should go for would help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need any Boolean algebra or any fancy mathematical logic. These topics are all developed using plain old common sense, which you already have plenty of. You just need a book that tells you how the formulas are derived and how the theorems are proved. Most good math books do this. You might find that you need to fill in gaps in your understanding of more basic topics in order to understand the more advanced stuff. It might help if you ask about a specific idea that you're having trouble understanding. (For example, do you already know how to derive the quadratic formula?)

Comment: That's true, I think my focus should be more on applying the operations and learning the laws. And yes I remember that one, never gave it any thought though. So does it work like: each step of deriving the quadratic formula (as an example) applies an algebraic law?  And each step logically comes from the former? I think my problem is wondering where each law comes in and how they interact with each other, just in general.

Comment: @aneveningsun There are no algebraic "laws", there are axioms of mathematical logic. If you want to be really formal in your foundations, you can start with the axioms of set theory, construct the real numbers, and deduce that they are a complete ordered field. But this might be a bit advanced for what you're looking for. The essential thing is that the real numbers $\mathbb R$ satisfy the 16 properties listed in the notes I linked. From these 16 properties, you can deduce all the algebraic properties of real numbers.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I definitely see now that I don't need to reinvent the wheel to go about learning these things. I think just understanding the properties will help with my problem-solving skills so I will focus on those. Thanks for the book!

Comment: @aneveningsun On the contrary, I think it's good that you are thinking about these things this way. But it is quite a rabbit hole, and the deeper you dig, the more you will find. It all depends what you choose as your "starting point". This led to a crisis in the early 20th century, about choosing a common "foundational theory" for mathematics. Nowadays the "true" starting point are the 9 axioms of [ZFC set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory). From these axioms, you can construct all mathematical objects and prove all properties about them.

Comment: But like I said, this is advanced for algebra. So what is usually done is, we assume we have a structure which behaves the way we want it to (like the real numbers) by listing a minimal set of properties we want them to exhibit. Then, from these properties, we squeeze as much as we can in the way of additional properties. This is why I did things that way in my notes, I basically just proved a lot of the properties which fields have. Other algebraic structures you could explore are groups and rings.

Answer (score 6):

The steps of algebra are justified by the fact that $\mathbb R$ is a field. The properties of fields are what we assume (as axioms), and all steps of algebra are justified by them. When I teach algebra to my A-level students, I first introduce them to this idea briefly, but then they get used to autopilot.

Have a look at section 1.2 of [these notes](https://drmenguin.com/files/ea.pdf#subsection.1.2), and see how a lot of things you do automatically are proved.

Think about some of the exercises in exercise 1.5: why is $x+x = 2x$? How can you solve $2x+1=3$ justifying *every* step?

Also take a look at how to solve a quadratic in this mind set by looking at examples 3.9(iii).